# Finding and connecting roots of undirected disconnected graph networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am new to NetworkX and I am trying to connect 4 disconnected components with a new common node.

I've just done this manually so far by listing all the nodes and taking one node from each component and connecting it to another node in the network

```
sorted(nx.connected_components(G))
G.add_edge(node1, node2) #connect two nodes in each disconnected component
```

EDIT: Realized I made an error in my question. Undirected graphs don't have a single root

Comment: I am not familiar with the term "root" in an undirected graph. Can you please provide a definition? I am guessing that it means a node which can connect to all other nodes, but am not sure if this is correct or not. If that is true, then isn't your strategy fine? You connect two roots, so they stay roots. I'm not sure what the other option is?

Comment: Oops I didn't think through that bit. But essentially, I'm trying to connect 4 disconnected trees by adding a common node. I did it manually by listing out the nodes and choosing 2 nodes in every tree to connect to, but I know there's a better way out there

Comment: Is there any criteria for which nodes should be selected to connect together, or is it totally arbitrary and doesn't matter? I feel like it's the latter, so there's not really a "better" way to do it than select a node at random in different components, and connect them. It's just arbitrary, so don't waste your time trying to make it not arbitrary. If there's some other metric (say edge weight, or connectivity, or something) you're trying to minimize/maximize/preserve, then that's a different story.

Comment: Start with a simple example: a component with two nodes, one edge connecting them, and another component which just contains a single node. How do you connect these? Does one way matter? Now add complexity---have one component with three nodes and two edges, and another component that is just a single node. How do you connect them? Is one way better than the others? Perhaps there's a rule lurking that you want to enforce but you just need to explicate what that rule is :)